# Howto force ssh to use a specific private key?

Tags: ssh, openssh, private-key

With `ssh -i <private key filename>` you can instruct ssh to use an *extra* private key to try authentication.

The documentation is not clear on how to explicitly use only that key.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can use the IdentitiesOnly option:

`ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i <private key filename> <hostname>`

from the man page for ssh_config(5):

```
  IdentitiesOnly
         Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the configured authentication identity and certificate files (either the default files, or those explicitly config‐
         ured in the ssh_config files or passed on the ssh(1) command-line), even if ssh-agent(1) or a PKCS11Provider or SecurityKeyProvider offers more identi‐
         ties.  The argument to this keyword must be yes or no (the default).  This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identi‐
         ties.
```

Comment: actually 'IdentitiesOnly' disables prompting ssh-agent, but still offers defaults and ssh_config'd keys.

Comment: The important thing for me was that it does not look in e.g. my ~/.ssh directory for keys to try.

Comment: Thanks! I needed the `-o "IdentitiesOnly=yes"` bit to prevent `ssh-agent` from overriding the private key specified.

Comment: This is super handy for determining which key works with a given host when you have keys cached in ssh-agent.  The only way I could figure it out without this flag was to use strace to dump the IO, which was pretty tedious.

Comment: You can also add `-v` to your `ssh` command to know which key is being used (add more `v` if one is not enough)

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me on macOS Big Sur’s SSH implementation

Comment: Downvote because it tries using `.ssh/id_rsa` which I have not specified with `-i`. Querstion as stated in title is not answered by this answer.

Comment: That's why the answer suggests to use the `-i` option to specify which key to use.

Comment: Thomas is right, even with `-o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i <private key filename>`, default `IdentityFile` keys in .ssh/config will be used before the identity specified. rogerovo said the same thing in 2014

Comment: What worked for me is this answer https://superuser.com/a/859719/445352 : in `.ssh/config` move any default `IdentityFile` entries inside a `Host * !<hostname>` block.  Then those identities will not be used when connecting to `<hostname>` but will still be used by default

Comment: See [brandon's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1777452) for how to actually only use the specified key.

Answer (score 22):

An alternative could be to generate a pair of keys using

```
ssh-keygen
```

and create a special configuration for the specified host and corresponding private key

Edit ~/.ssh/config

```
Host handy_server
    HostName x.y.z.w
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/handy
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User userk
    Port 22
```

Comment: Yes IdentityFile should point to the private key file. Now updated.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since all identify files in the config will be attempted, for example "HostName *" entries. From the ssh_config man page: "It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence."

Comment: @brandon This seems to answer the question of "Howto force ssh to use a specific private key?" since it the `IdentityFile` is the specific private key you're using. I didn't specify the `HostName` for my entry in my config file and it didn't seem to matter.

This is a better answer than the accepted one since I just wanted to copy + paste stuff to my ~/.ssh/config file and modify accordingly. Sometimes doing everything from command line is a bit overkill imo.

Comment: @hellatan, It uses *all* applicable identity files, as stated in the man page, rather than a specific one. See my replies to my answer below for details.
It worked for you because it tries *all* of them, including the right one. You can use -v to see all the files it tried. Maybe it only tried one in your specific setup, but, but it will attempt others, rather than just a specific one, which can cause a failure in some cases (like "too many attempts").

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is incorrect, since all identity files in the default config will also be used in addition to those specified with the `-i` arguments. This can be a problem if the device you're connecting to has an authentication attempt limit that can be exceeded before eventually getting to the correct key.

To force it to use the single private key file, and only that key, you can specify a nonexistent config file with the `-F` argument:

```
ssh -F /dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i <private key filename> <hostname>
```

Using the `-v` argument will show the keys being used. You should now see that only one is used. Look for "Will attempt key: " lines.

Comment: Seconding this, the accepted answer still tried my ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 file, while this one only tries the given key. See also @rogerovo comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Adding `-F` seems to be only needed if you explicitly set an IdentityFile in your config. 
In that case adding `-o "IdentityFile=/dev/null"` might be a safer option, not losing any other config you might have.

Comment: @Peregrino69, the man page for ssh_config correctly states that only identity files configured will be used for the connection, for any config file used. The problem is, the default config file (~./ssh/config) is used by default, requiring the -F to specify a different config, and *not* use the default. Many of us have "Host *" type entries in our default config, for devices without fixed IPs.

See the `ssh` man page for details, since -F is a an `ssh` argument.

Comment: @HermanvanRink, I just double checked, and this doesn't work. As the ssh_config man page states, "It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence.". Without -F pointing to a different file, the default (usually ~/.ssh/config) is used on top of any -o options (see `ssh` man page for -F argument). If there are matching entries in that default config, like 'Host *', they will all be used. -v shows the configuration files loaded, and the identify files used.