# Need to skip password entry in script

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, putty, plink

Have a shell script on Unix server, that is needed to be launched by another script from Windows machine. And the problem is that script on Windows machine has to get a key-fingerprint (its located on the ftp server) to skip password entry and I don't know how to do it. Need your help guys!

Comment: Hiding the sensible information, can you add the line that launch the unix script from the windows one?

Comment: Have a good tailoring.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147283/3569208)] putty usually comes with the "plink" utility.

> This is essentially the "ssh" command line command implemented as a windows .exe.
> It pretty well documented in the putty manual under "**Using the command line tool plink**".
> You just need to wrap a command like:
>
> **plink root@myserver /etc/backups/do-backup.sh**

From the comment of the same answer it comes out that

> In addition you can use **pageant to allow the key to be loaded** and used so there is no need to enter the key's passphrase each time.

In another answer it is reported [[2](http://pythianpang.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/let-putty-run-command-in-remote-server/)] to use a command line as

```
putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m c:remote.cmd remote_host
```

of course you can add the specification you need for the ssh-keys you need.

You can find interesting to read more on the manual of putty, for example in the section 4.17 [[3](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.53/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.17)], some example [[4](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-execute-a-remote-script-unix/)], the ssh manual [[5](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh&sec=1)]... and last but not least *"Howto force ssh to use a specific private key"* [[6](https://superuser.com/a/773135/257269)] reported her below:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i <private key filename> <hostname>
```